# Is my "insertion sort" correct?

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I am writing an insertion sort code in C. This code is perfectly working. But I am a bit confused if my implementation is correct or not for *insertion sort*.

```c
//insertion sort algorithm
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insertion_sort(int size, int *arr);

int main(void)
{
    int *array;
    int size;

    printf("enter the amount of data: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    insertion_sort(size, array);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void insertion_sort(int size, int *arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(arr[i] < arr[i - 1])
        {
            int temp;
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
            arr[i - 1] = temp;

            i -= 2;

            //with this testing, you can see the number while the data still sorted
            /* for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j) */
            /* { */
            /*  printf("%d ", arr[j]); */
            /* } */
            /* printf("\n"); */
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We review code that the author knows to be working. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you asking whether this sorts correctly, or whether this is a true implementation of *insertion sort*?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm). It presents two implementations of the insertion sort:

1. Swapping insertion sort,
2. Faster insertion sort.

In C, (1) would seem like:

```
static void swap(int* arr, size_t higher_index) {
    int tmp = arr[higher_index];
    arr[higher_index] = arr[higher_index - 1];
    arr[higher_index - 1] = tmp;
}

void insertion_sort_v2(int* arr, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        size_t j = i;

        while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
            swap(arr, j);
            --j;
        }
    }
}
```

(2) would seem like:

```
void insertion_sort_v3(int* arr, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        int x = arr[i];
        size_t j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > x) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            --j;
        }

        arr[j + 1] = x;
    }
}
```

(2) is more efficient than (1) since it makes a single assignment per element move. ((1) makes a swap consisting of 3 assignments.)

**Advice 1**

I believe more customary argument list might be `insertion_sort(int* array, size_t size)`.

**Advice 2**

Now, back to your code.

```
if(i == 0)
{
    continue;
}
```

You can omit the above by starting from loop index `i = 1`. By the way, the type of the loop index `i` should be `size_t`, not `int`.

**Advice 3**

```
if(arr[i] < arr[i - 1])
```

So, `arr[i]` is on the right and `arr[i - 1]` is on the left in the array. Why not swap the order to make it more readable? Also, you should have a single space between `if` and condition opening `(`:

```
if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i])
```

**Advice 4**

```
else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

That's completely unnecessary. Get rid of it.

**Summa summarum**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /* Visual Studio 2022 specific */
#define N 50000
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void insertion_sort(int size, int* arr);
void insertion_sort_v2(int* arr, size_t length);
void insertion_sort_v3(int* arr, size_t length);

static size_t millis() {
    return clock() / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
}

static int arrays_equal(int* array1, int* array2, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

static int array_is_sorted(int* array, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

static void benchmark() {
    int* array1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    int* array2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    int* array3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

    srand(4);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        array1[i] = array2[i] = array3[i] = rand();
    }

    size_t start_time = millis();
    insertion_sort(N, array1);
    size_t end_time = millis();
    printf("OP insertion sort in %d milliseconds.\n", end_time - start_time);

    start_time = millis();
    insertion_sort_v2(array2, N);
    end_time = millis();
    printf("insertion sort v2 in %d milliseconds.\n", end_time - start_time);

    start_time = millis();
    insertion_sort_v3(array3, N);
    end_time = millis();
    printf("insertion sort v3 in %d milliseconds.\n", end_time - start_time);

    int equal = arrays_equal(array1, array2, N) &&
                arrays_equal(array2, array3, N);

    printf("Arrays are equal: %d\n", equal);

    if (equal) {
        printf("Arrays are sorted: %d\n", array_is_sorted(array1, N));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int* array;
    int size;

    printf("enter the amount of data: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    insertion_sort_v3(array, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    benchmark();

    return 0;
}

void insertion_sort(int size, int* arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1])
        {
            int temp;
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
            arr[i - 1] = temp;

            i -= 2;

            //with this testing, you can see the number while the data still sorted
            /* for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j) */
            /* { */
            /*  printf("%d ", arr[j]); */
            /* } */
            /* printf("\n"); */
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}

static void swap(int* arr, size_t higher_index) {
    int tmp = arr[higher_index];
    arr[higher_index] = arr[higher_index - 1];
    arr[higher_index - 1] = tmp;
}

void insertion_sort_v2(int* arr, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
        size_t j = i;

        while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
            swap(arr, j);
            --j;
        }
    }
}

void insertion_sort_v3(int* arr, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
        int x = arr[i];
        size_t j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > x) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            --j;
        }

        arr[j + 1] = x;
    }
}
```

The above program outputs:

```
enter the amount of data: 0

OP insertion sort in 1555 milliseconds.
insertion sort v2 in 699 milliseconds.
insertion sort v3 in 338 milliseconds.
Arrays are equal: 0
```

Above, you can see that your implementation is both incorrect and slow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `You can omit [if (i == 0) continue;] by starting from loop index i = 1.` *if `i` doesn't get a chance to be 0 later on*. But irritating as manipulating an iteration variable "manually" is, "moving down" any value smaller than all the ones already ordered (avoidably) gets there.

Comment: `you can see that [OP's implementation is] incorrect` actually, I can't from the code&output provided: Add the line from `array_is_sorted(array1, N)`. FWIW, I failed to reproduce `equal: 0` on tutorialspoint.com's coding ground.

Comment: @greybeard Your dexterity amazes me, pal! Did you actually debugged the OP code, or do you spot those points on your own?

Comment: (Not *quite* certain if you are pulling my leg. I don't have a local debugging environment but for Java (8, as it happens), and I didn't find one with tutorialspoint.)

Comment: Nice answer. However, the testing is still incomplete; all three algorithms could be broken in the same way and your test suite would not catch it. The proper way is to check that apart from being sorted, the output is a permutation of the original input. See also [this article from Kevlin Henney](https://kevlinhenney.medium.com/test-precisely-and-concretely-810a83f6309a).

Comment: "more customary argument list might be insertion_sort(int* array, size_t size" may be true yet with `size` first, as in `insertion_sort(size_t size, int array[size])`, (and with VLA support) allows for static analysis possibilities.

Comment: Minor: `clock() / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000)` incurs unnecessary lost of precision when `CLOCKS_PER_SEC % 1000 != 0`.  `clock() * 1000LL / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is somewhat better.  Using `size_t` for time is strange - suggest `long long` or `double`.  Using `size_t` with `"%d"` can lead to _undefined behavior_..

Answer (score 2):

Don't write, never publish/commit undocumented code.

I think your `insertion_sort()` does not truthfully implement *insertion sort*:
While it terminates the search for the "insertion point" on the first non-greater value encountered,
it re-compares all the values "just moved up" and known to be ordered.

There are two copies of a loop to print all the values in a array
(if one is "commented out"):
Make *doing the same in more than one place* a procedure, as a bonus you get to give it a name.

I don't like an `else` after `if (condition) continue;` (or `break` or `return`).

Manipulation of a *loop control variable* in the midst of a loop is unexpected and hard to follow - all the more so with a ("C family") `for`-loop where the third expression's side effects can be avoided only by breaking out of the loop.

Comment: actually, I wrote that `if` and `else` for prevent code break if the user enter a negative number on the input(and it works!).

Comment: Such an `else` is entirely redundant.